# Kivy AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids' but why?

Tags: list, kivy, attributeerror, ids

here main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem, MDList

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass



class Example(MDApp):
    lst_matches = ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_start(self):
        # List of possible crossword candidates.
        for i in range(20):
            self.root.ids.lst_matches.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}"))

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

Example().run()
```

and then the main.kv file

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        lst_matches: lst_matches
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ScrollView:
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: 0.5
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            MDList:
                id: lst_matches
```

i added ObjectProperty(None) to lst_matches and correct the .kv file with lst_matches: lst_matches
and then..

File "C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\test kivy da lista\main.py", line 17, in on_start
self.root.ids.lst_matches.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}"))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'

but i can't understand why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning the output of `Builder.load_file("main.kv")` from your `build()` method. However, that `kv` file does not create any widgets, so your `root` widget is `None`. The fix is a simple change to your `build()` method:

```
def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
    Builder.load_file("main.kv")
    return MyLayout()
```

In a `kv` file, the `<>` construction creates a rule for how a specific widget is to be built, but it does not actually create a widget. The `Builder.load_file()` loads the rule from your `kv` file, and the `return MyLayout()` actually creates an instance of `MyLayout` in accordance with the `kv` file rule.